# O que significa dois asteriscos antes de nome em C++?

Tags: c++

char **argv

O que esses dois asteriscos significam?

Comment: Ponteiro para ponteiro de char.

Comment: Recomendo olhar este vídeo, bem didático: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2-GllOuAYFE

Comment: Obrigado a todos!